# Format AngularJS ng-repeat text obtained from Laravel API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel

I have a Laravel 5.2 Backend API and a AngularJS Frontend and at some point I perform a laravel validation and return and error if validation fails.

When I iterate trough errors and display them on the frontend I get somthing like this:

```
["The email has already been taken."]
```

and I would like to be like this

```
The email has already been taken.
```

without the [""] stuff.

My code is:

Angular controller:

```
if (error.statusText === "Unprocessable Entity") {

          $scope.registerErrors = error.data;
}
```

Angular template:

```
<div class="alert alert-warning animated pulse" ng-if="registerError && isLoading === false">
<p ng-repeat="(error, errorText) in registerErrors">{{errorText}}</p>
</div>
```

Laravel controller:

```
$this->validate($request, [
          'firstname' => 'required|max:100|min:3',
          'lastname' => 'required|max:100|min:3',
          'email' => 'required|email|unique:users|max:255',
]);
```

Console.log:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use a filter that replaces `/[\[\]\'\"]/g` with `''`?

Comment: I will try to make a custom filter ... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because of `errorText` contain `email` array and you shown full email array. if email contain multiple error then
can try like:

```
<p ng-repeat="(error, errorObject) in registerErrors">
  <span ng-repeat=" singleError in errorObject">{{singleError}}</span>
</p>
```

or for single error can try like:

```
<p ng-repeat="(error, errorText) in registerErrors">{{errorText[0]}}</p>
```

or just assign `error.data.email` instead of `error.data`

```
if (error.statusText === "Unprocessable Entity") {
     $scope.registerErrors = error.data.email;
}
```

Comment: use `span` tag in `p` tag should be work updated my answer @vitaminasweb

Comment: It's working! I have some doubts on what will happens if error.data will contain and array of arrays ... I tried to simulate several validation fails on the backend and it seams that laravel return the first encountered error when using $this->validate($request ... It's ok for me. Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need change `$scope.registerErrors = error.data;` into `$scope.registerErrors = error.data.email;`. Because `error.data.email` is an array.

If you have several errors at the same time, it's better to try this

```
if (error.statusText === "Unprocessable Entity") {
      $scope.registerErrors=[];
      if(error.data.email)$scope.registerErrors.push(error.data.email[0]);
      if(error.data.firstname)$scope.registerErrors.push(error.data.firstname[0]);
      if(error.data.lastname)$scope.registerErrors.push(error.data.lastname[0]);
}
```

Comment: The error.data will not always contain just email, could contain other several errors in the same time ... for that reason I use ng-repeat

Comment: You can add the cases of firstname and lastname, I've updated the answer

Comment: If you have several errors at the same time, you can see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, hope it could be helpful

Comment: Yes it is. But I already marked as correct other answer. Your solution seams very god too. I sew it late . :( ... Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/udr9dksa/

```
{{emailTaken | cleanError}}
```

**Filter:**

```
app.filter("cleanError", function() {
    return function(input) {
    if(!input) return "";

    return input.slice(2, -2);
  }
});
```

Comment: For some reason it's not work well ... I get as response only [ ]